# Помогите разобраться с частью кода kohana

Tags: php, kohana, объекты

Всем доброе время суток.
Сидел на Delphi, полгода назад пересел на Php, сейчас по чуть-чуть разбираюсь с кодом kohana (до этого было все просто).  
Не могу понять, где начинает использоваться параметр.
В kohana для создания объекта используется запись, например:

```
$one_department_a = ORM::factory('department', $id)
```

Из кода ("…\orm\classes\Kohana\ORM.php"):

```
public static function factory($model, $id = NULL)  
    {// Set class name  
        $model = 'Model_'.$model;  
        return new $model($id);}
```

следует, что создается копия (модель) `Model___department`, класс/файл (`class Model_department extends ORM`), который я заведомо сделал.  
Я не пойму, в каком месте используется `$id` (просмотрел все родители).

Comment: $id это параметр который передаются в конструктор вызванной модели, и по умолчанию он null.

Comment: factory(модель, id записи)

по сути тоже самое что и 

    factory('user')->where('id', '=', 20)->find()

Comment: ID я передаю, извиняюсь, я не могу найти конструктор, в классе.

Comment: @Konstantin78, нет, в данном случае конструктор называется ``__construct()`` и находится в том же классе, что и ``factory()``: см [ORM.php:252 на github](https://github.com/kohana/orm/blob/3.3/master/classes/Kohana/ORM.php#L252)

Comment: Да, да я уже нашел, спасибо. Можно было, конечно, в отладчике самому посмотреть, что в какой последовательности выполняется.

Answer (score 1):

У класса ORM есть конструктор, который принимает `$id`

```
public function __construct($id = NULL)
{
    $this->_initialize();
    //...
}
```